# Iterations as vectors

Tags: r

I'm doing a series of replications from a series of subsets of the form

```
pseudo = replicate(10, sample(sub_data$Y1,10))
```

I am able to obtain a data.frame where each iteration is a column

```
sub_data     iteration 1    iteration2    iteration...10  
a
a
a
a
a
b
b
b
b
b
```

but i need it to be of the form

```
sub_data  ITERATION      Y1
a          1 
a          1
a          2
a          2
a          3
a          3
b          1 
b          1
b          2
b          2
b          3
b          3
```

Is there any simple way??

Comment: Could you please provide reproducible code, e.g., by providing the output of `dput(sub_data)`?

Comment: res1=ddply(corr, .(corr$Target), function(sub_data) 
{
   pseudo = replicate(10, sample(sub_data$MVP,14))
   return(data.frame(pseudo))
}
)

Comment: This is still not reproducible (what is `corr`?). Please create a minimal working example of what your problem is, which we can copy and paste into our R instances. (In fact, creating such a minimal working example may help you solve it yourself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your first `data.frame` you "reshape" it using `melt from the`reshape2` package do do exactly this.

```
melt(yourdata, id.vars='sub_data')
```

Take a look at the help for `?melt.data.frame` for some additional naming parameters.

You can also use base R for this, but I find the syntax more difficult.